# CSS3 background

Tags: css, html5, css3

Estoy tratando de insertar una foto en mi página, usé la siguiente información para poner la foto:

```
background-image: url(../../Pictures/espacio.img);
background-position:center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

El resultado no fue el que esperaba, la foto se ve muy *pixeleada*, ya que se esparció por toda la página.

¿Qué necesito agregar para que la foto se vea bien?

Comment: ¿Cómo debería verse?, ¿del tamaño original?

Comment: pues deberias proporcinar mas informacion al respecto si quieres ayuda. Prueba copiando el codigo donde usaste la imagen, los estilos que usaste, si esta o no dentro de otro div, cuales proporciones tienen estos div...etc..

Debes tener en cuenta que al usar una imagen para background, el tamaño del contenedor de esta no puede ser mayor al tamaño d ela foto, porque esta va a perder calidad....es por eso importante que puedas compartir tu codigo para determinar que se puede hacer...

Comment: Probaste con `background-size: auto;` ?

Comment: ya, creo que el problema es porque la imagen la guarde directamente de google y la inserte tal y como estaba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes tener en cuenta que... si la imagen es menor tamaño que tu pantalla y utilizas la propiedad `background-size: cover;` Lo que haces con ello es forzar la imagen a que CUBRA todo el contenido o tamaño donde estes poniendo tu imagen.

Si quieres esa foto si o si, tienes dos opciones:

1) Crear esa misma imagen en mayor tamaño que sea igual o superior al tamaño donde se va a mostrar, por lo que dejará de pixelarse

2) Reducir el tamaño donde muestras la imagen y esto es eliminando la propiedad que usaste `background-size: cover;` y le das un `height` y ``width` a tu imagen pero claro, será tan tan grande como la imagen en si misma sea. Nunca debemos olvidar que el código modifica lo que ya tienes. Si tu imagen es pequeña..agrandarla siempre va a pixelar. Saludos! =)

Comment: perfecto, gracias!

Comment: Para eso estamos. Recuerda valorar positivamente la solución para que otros puedan encontrarla antes. Saludos!